# Grails: How to reduce DB queries

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, grails, hql

I am showing the completion percentage of a task using a progress bar. To get the completion percentage I am using countBy method:

```
DomainA.countByZ(z) > 0 ? Status.COMPLETE : Status.INCOMPLETE
```

I have ten queries like this.

Each time when I got status completed I increase a counter by one and at the end divide it by ten to get the average.

To get the percentage it hit ten DB queries

```
select count(*) as y0_ from domain_a this_ where this_.z_id=?
select count(*) as y0_ from domain_b this_ where this_.z_id=?
...
```

Is there any way to reduce the number of queries?(by using hql query or any other way to get average or count).

I googled the same but didn't get relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you cannot use `HQL` to query entities that hasn't relationships, so the solution is to use native sql in this case. You can do it in an service:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class MyService {
  def dataSource

  int myCalc() {
    Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    String query = """
select count(*) tot1, 
       (select count(*) from domain_class2) as tot2
  from domain_class1
"""
    def row = sql.firstRow(query)
    //access properties directly
    println row.tot1
    println row.tot2
  }
}
```

Comment: My `logSql` is true. I can see my the `DomainA.countByZ(z)` DB his in console but native sql DB hits are not shown in the console. I don't know whether grails shows native sql hits or not. How can I see native sql DB hits?

Comment: add `groovy.sql` package as level `debug` in log4j configuration.

Comment: this gives me===`2013-11-27 23:40:34,962 [http-bio-80-exec-5] DEBUG sql.Sql  - select count(*) tot1,
(select count(*) from achievement) as tot2,
(select count(*) from article) as tot3,
from address
===5======0=======18========
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from address this_
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from achievement this_
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from article this_
===5======0=======18======`

Comment: looks like one query, I am not confirmed.

Comment: Yes, one query. Groovy's Sql class will not create query's unless you call the methods.